# Updating composer autoloader after moving modules

Tags: 8, composer

I have been using composer to install all Drupal modules, when I realized that they had not been installing to modules/contrib. So, I added this into my composer file:

```
"installer-paths": {
  "modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"]
}
```

Then, I moved all modules to /contrib under the modules directory, and rebuilt my cache with `drush cr`. No errors.

Now I cannot reload the site, I am getting fatal errors about missing modules at their old paths.

How do I clear the autoloader so it gets updated to look in modules/contrib instead of just modules for class files?

Attached picture of the error.[image]

I tried removing the composer.lock file and running `composer update` - no dice.

#### Update

Looks like I did everything right, I just needed to reboot the VM to clear the APC cache.

Is there a way I could do that from command line *instead* of reboot the server?

Comment: This may or may not be a result of https://www.drupal.org/node/2776235

Answer (score 1):

I am using this to refresh module paths. I tried all other combos with apc_clear_cache etc and didnt help, also nginx restart didnt help, this 2 did.

```
service php7.2-fpm restart 
drush cr
```

Comment: It may help to explain a bit about why this would help answer the question rather than write out some commands. For instance, I think that restarting php-fpm will clear any opcache, but that may not necessarily be the case on all systems, and doing a cache-refresh in Drupal will force the Symfony/Drupal service container to be rebuilt.

Comment: I added a bit more context. I tried it all many times, testing for hours and only this combo worked every time.